# How can I indent a paragraph that comes after a list in LyX?

Tags: lyx

I'm writing a document in LyX. I would like every new Paragraph to be indented, and it does happen to all paragraphs beside ones that are in a new section/subsection or coming after a list.
Is there a way to fix that?

(sorry if it's an extremely basic question, I couldn't find the answer anywhere)

This is what I get:

```
Subsection
first paragraph is not indent.
    second one is
    third one is 
    list:
 1. something
 2. something else
 again not indent.
```

and I would like it to be:

```
Subsection
    first paragraph is indent.
    second one is
    third one is 
    list:
 1. something
 2. something else
    indent again!
```

Comment: You can find the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67378/in-lyx-how-do-i-indent-the-paragraph-right-after-an-itemize-enumerate-environme).

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a LaTeX command (ctrl+l or insert->TeX Code) at any place in your document.

Just place your cursor at the beginning of the line you wish to force indentation on, press ctrl+l and add the code "\indent".